# Unresolved Kotlin references after updating Android Studio to 2020.3.1 Canary 14 Build

Tags: android, kotlin

I am currently experiencing Android Studio warning me about certain Kotlin functions that don't exist. I assume this is an Android Studio only problem as I can compile and run my project just fine

For example, Android Studio is unable to recognize `val rows = mutableListOf<MeasuredRow>()`. It provides the warning: `Unresolved reference: mutableListOf`. That said, I can use some other Kotlin functions and classes just fine.

The only solution is downgrading which I do *not* want to do

App-wide gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.32"
    ext.compose_version = '1.0.0-beta04'
    ext.hilt_version = '2.33-beta'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0-alpha14'
        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:$hilt_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }

    tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).configureEach {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = '1.8'
            allWarningsAsErrors = false
            // Opt-in to experimental compose APIs
            freeCompilerArgs += '-Xopt-in=kotlin.RequiresOptIn'
            // Enable experimental coroutines APIs, including collectAsState()
            freeCompilerArgs += '-Xopt-in=kotlinx.coroutines.ExperimentalCoroutinesApi'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

App module specific Gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildscript {
        apply from: '../dependencies.gradle'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.0.0-beta04'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            debuggable false
            shrinkResources = true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'

    implementation "androidx.compose.compiler:compiler:1.0.0-beta04"
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.0.0-beta04'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.0.0-beta04'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:1.0.0-beta04'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.0.0-beta04'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.0-alpha06'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:1.0.0-beta04'
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:1.0.0-alpha09"
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0-alpha01"
    implementation 'dev.chrisbanes.accompanist:accompanist-insets:0.6.2'

    // ViewModel
    def lifecycle_version = "2.3.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:1.0.0-alpha04'
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"

    // hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:$hilt_version"

    // Image Loading
    implementation group: 'com.google.accompanist', name: 'accompanist-imageloading-core', version: '0.7.0'
    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-glide:0.7.0"
}
```

It is important to know that my app works and is installable with no issues (even on a clean install)

What I've tried:

- Reinstall Windows PC
- Invalidate Cache/Restart
- Delete .Android studio in home directory
- Delete ./.idea folder

Comment: I encountered this problem as well just now and I am very dissapointed as this hampers the current project I am working on. The perils of working on unstable releases. Are you working on Jetpack Compose? At this point I will be downgrading to Canary 8 as this was the last version that was stable for me.

Comment: @NeonWarge correct. this is a Compose project. In the end I decided to revert to an older version

Comment: I have heard similar complaints from others, such as in the `#compose` channel in Kotlinlang Slack. Personally, I stopped my Canary upgrade cycle at 12, mostly due to the Gradle 7.0 change -- I'll wait until Arctic Fox his beta before making that move. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/185562147 and https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/183816740 may be related. However, neither issue seems to have a sample project. If anyone seeing this is in position to create a project that reproduces the problem and can add that to an issue, that might help expedite repairs.

Answer (score -2):

It works now for me.

AS 2020.3.1 canary 15

Kotlin 1.5.0